# Error: java.lang.NullPointerException (Java/Netbeans//Mysql)

Tags: java, jdbc

I developed an application in java netbeans with a parser that reads data from a text file (. txt).

He reads this file 5 in 5 minutes and writes the values ​​in the database. 
The problem is that after two hours of running the program it fails to record and retrieve data from the database and gives this error:

Exception in thread java.lang.NullPointerException

Does anyone can tell me why this is happening please?

Thanks for the help.

--------------------------------Edit(Code)-------------------------------------------

```
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conexao = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bdtest", "root", "root");
        Statement stm = conexao.createStatement();


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/RPR1BRG/Desktop/test.txt"));

        String dados[] = new String[6];
        String linha = reader.readLine();

        while (linha != null) {

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(linha, ";\"");

            dados[0] = st.nextToken();
            dados[1] = st.nextToken(); 
            dados[2] = st.nextToken();
            dados[3] = st.nextToken();
            dados[4] = st.nextToken();
            dados[5] = st.nextToken();


            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yy");

PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) conexao.prepareStatement("replace into registos" + " (data_registo, hora_registo, IdSensor, Temperatura, Humidade, pt_orvalho) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");


               try {
                 stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.parse(dados[0]).getTime()));
                        stmt.setString(2, dados[1]);
                        stmt.setString(3, dados[2]);
                        stmt.setString(4, dados[3]);
                        stmt.setString(5, dados[4]);
                        stmt.setString(6, dados[5]);



                    } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
                        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
                    }



    stmt.executeUpdate();





            linha = reader.readLine();

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/RPR1BRG/Desktop/test.txt"); 
            writer.print("");
            writer.close();

            }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | IOException e) {

        System.err.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());

    }


        }
    };
```

Comment: Post your code and the stacktrace.

Comment: How do you suppose we can help you without looking at the code or stacktrace? See [how to ask question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I' m sorry for failing to post the code!

Comment: And the stacktrace...

Comment: Sorry again!! To get the stacktrace I need to wait until the application gives the error again because I already deleted :(

Comment: By the way, if you're using a `PreparedStatement`, you don't need to create it multiple times when performing the same SQL sentence, just change the parameters. Also, if you're inserting multiple rows from a same query in your database, it would be better using batch update (per multiple rows at a single time) instead of plain update (per row).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And sorry for my ignorance.

But in practical terms how can I do that you say?

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement("replace into registos"
    + " (data_registo, hora_registo, IdSensor, Temperatura, Humidade, pt_orvalho)"
    + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Close the file explicitly.

```
reader.close();
```

after the loop. Close the statement after the loop:

```
stmt.close();
```

**The error** might have been caused by data.

Maybe better with dumping the line when data are missing:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            dados[i] = st.hasMoreTokens()? st.nextToken() : "";
        }
```

instead of

```
        dados[0] = st.nextToken();
        dados[1] = st.nextToken(); 
        dados[2] = st.nextToken();
        dados[3] = st.nextToken();
        dados[4] = st.nextToken();
        dados[5] = st.nextToken();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...
When I try your suggestion, this error appears: Error: Stream closed

Comment: Sorry wrong formulation corrected, `reader.close()` of course should be done _after_ the loop.